# React change state embedded object

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple question, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here is my initial state:

```
 getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            selector:{
                params:{
                    platform:'BITSTAMP',
                    currency:'USD',
                    item:'BTC',
                    interval:'15m',
                    range:'1d'
                }
            },
            platforms: [],
            pairs: [],
            allPlatforms: {},
            range: ['12h','1d','3d','1w','2w','1m','3m','6m','1y','Max', 'Custom'],
            interval: ['1m','15m','1h','6h','12h','24h']
        }
   },
```

Let's say I need to change `selector.params.platform`. If I write:

```
this.setState({
    selector: {
        params: {
            platform: "somenewplatform"
        }
    }
});
```

It will destroy my other params keeping only platform. So what I'm doing is

```
 var newState = this.state;
 newState.selector.params.platform = "newplatform";
```

Then I `setState({selector:newState});`

Is it the right way to do this? Knowing that `newState.selector.params.platform = "newplatform";` means modifying the state directly without going through `setState` directly, I'm not sure this is the right thing to do.

So if anyone has a better solution I'll be really curious to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do

```
var newState = this.state;
newState.selector.params.platform = "newplatform";
this.setState({selector:newState});
```

This will set `this.state.selector` to be your entire state object. It looks like what you want is this:

```
var newSelector = this.state.selector;
newSelector.params.platform = "newplatform";
this.setState({selector: newSelector});
```